# Using p/invoke and win-api to monitor audio line-in (C#)

Tags: c#, winapi, audio, pinvoke

In the last few days I was trying to write small program to monitor the audio  line-in using win-api (winmm.dll).
I can pinvoke api functions such as waveInOpen but I can't figure out how to use these functions to achieve my target.

the question is - can someone can briefly tell me how can I get the data from the audio line in using these API (C#).

Comment: Have you tried http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.waveInOpen? It has the sample code

Comment: Hi Aziz- I did try this great api wiki. I can call waveInOpen but don't know what to do with the handler I get. it is useless even in waveInGetDevCaps.

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally found what I was looking for here.

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-264694.html

Although this is a C code example, it is depicting the simple outline of using the windows audio api to read data from the sound-card line-in/microphone device.

I am now working on recodeing this C code to C#. if successful I will post it here.

Comment: were you able to convert the code? I just need to check if the microphone is being used or not

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to!!!

Look this:

[Measure speaker volume by recording playing sound with microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955253/measure-speaker-volume-by-recording-playing-sound-with-microphone/3979900#3979900)

Join forces with the guy :)

Comment: nice thanx. I have to do something simple so I will probably will dig into the code to get only the functionality that I need. but it is very helpful