# How do I figure out if Windows is currently playing any sounds?

Tags: c#

How can I figure out if Windows is currently playing any sounds through the primary audio device? I need to know, so that I can make my program automatically adjust its volume.

Comment: what is exactly the idea? adjust the volume when playing sound? and do nothing when not playing sound? can you please explain a bit more in depth?

Comment: I think this is better suited to super user

Comment: Why? It's a programming question. I want to know how to detect it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to mess around with mixer controls.

[Mixer Control](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931)

These may help ya out too.

[Measure speaker volume by recording playing sound with microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955253/measure-speaker-volume-by-recording-playing-sound-with-microphone/3979900#3979900)

[Using p/invoke and win-api to monitor audio line-in (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931757/using-p-invoke-and-win-api-to-monitor-audio-line-in-c)

Comment: -1 : none of these links actually answers the OP's question. They can be useful, but still to generic to deliver a solution to the problem here.

Answer (score 6):

You could use CSCore.
Download it right here -> http://cscore.codeplex.com/

Paste these lines on a console project.

```
using System;
using CSCore.CoreAudioAPI;

namespace AudioDetector
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IsAudioPlaying(GetDefaultRenderDevice()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static MMDevice GetDefaultRenderDevice()
        {
            using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
            {
                return enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);
            }
        }

        public static bool IsAudioPlaying(MMDevice device)
        {
            using (var meter = AudioMeterInformation.FromDevice(device))
            {
                return meter.PeakValue > 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Play a music be it on YouTube, Music Player, etc...
Run the program.
It automatically notifies(true/false) if there is an audio currently being played or not.