# Detect any video playing on Windows OS (7,8,10)

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I am search for a way to detect if video is playing on Windows OS (7,8,10).

SetThreadExecutionState api function does not help I have tryied with different players (VLC, BS player etc.) but it seems they don't use flag ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED.

Checking for disabled screensaver is not good solution, because it should be allowed at first place and almost nobody use screensavers nowdays.

My app is a break timer, I am using LASTINPUTINFO() function but I want to know 
 when the user is watching video because there is not input (keyboard or mouse) during this time.

A dirty and partial solution would be if the app does snapshot of region in the center of the screen and comparing hashes, but it will be 90% accurate.

Any better ideas?

Comment: There is no single reliable way to do what you are asking for. Every video player is different, playing video in its own way, and no video player registers with the OS when it is playing video.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe there's a different approach for solving your [real problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Detecting current audio activity is simpler, E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616227/how-do-i-figure-out-if-windows-is-currently-playing-any-sounds

Comment: @AlexK. thanks but detecting audio is not a solution

Comment: @vinsa did you find a solution for this question?